# cannot resolve symbol 'google' in android studio

Tags: android

`var origin = new google.maps.LatLng( location.latitude, location.longitude );`

The above code shows `error` as `cannot resolve symbol google`. which `google api` i have to use in order to resolve it.

Comment: `import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In Eclipse goto File ⇒ Import ⇒ Android ⇒ Existing Android Code Into Workspace
> 2. Click on Browse and select Google Play Services project from your android sdk folder. You can locate play services library project from
>      android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
> 3. Importantly while importing check Copy projects into workspace option

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have added Google Play Services Library as Library
  project.
- if problem persists update your Google Play Service Library by SDK
  Manager.
- do Clean and ReBuild project.
- please restart your Eclipse or andorid
  studio,

refer :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/